# Оптимизация кода по времени исполнения

Tags: python, оптимизация

```py
import sys
t = int(sys.stdin.readline())
for i in range(t):
x1, p1 = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
x2, p2 = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
 if int((str(x1) + '0'*p1)) > int((str(x2) + '0'*p2)):
     print('>')
 elif int((str(x1) + '0'*p1)) < int((str(x2) + '0'*p2)):
     print('<')
 elif int((str(x1) + '0'*p1)) ==  int((str(x2) + '0'*p2)):
     print('=')
```

```
A. Длинное сравнение
ограничение по времени на тест 2 секунды
ограничение по памяти на тест 256 мегабайт
ввод
стандартный ввод
вывод
стандартный вывод
```

Монокарп выписал на доске два числа. Оба заданы в следующем формате: положительное целое число `x`, к концу которому приписаны `p` нулей.
Теперь Монокарп просит вас сравнить эти два числа. Можете ему помочь?

Входные данные

В первой строке записано одно целое число `t`(1≤t≤10<sup>4</sup>) — количество наборов входных данных.

В первой строке каждого набора входных данных записаны два целых числа `x1` и `p1` (1≤x1≤10<sup>6</sup>; 0≤p1≤10<sup>6</sup>) — описание первого числа.
Во второй строке каждого набора входных данных записаны два целых числа `x2` и `p2` (1≤x2≤10<sup>6</sup>; 0≤p2≤10<sup>6</sup>) — описание второго числа.

Выходные данные

На каждый набор входных данных выведите результат сравнения двух данных чисел. Если первое число меньше второго, то выведите '<'. Если первое число больше второго, то выведите '>'. Если они равны, то выведите '='.

Пример:

Входные данные
5
2 1
19 0
10 2
100 1
1999 0
2 3
1 0
1 0
99 0
1 2

Выходные данные
>
=
<
=
<

Примечание:
Сравнения в примере: 20>19, 1000=1000, 1999<2000, 1=1, 99<100.

Comment: а что этот код делает

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пихайте в заголовок темы что-либо кроме тезиса, отражающего суть проблемы. Во-вторых, поясните, что вам в конечном итоге требуется.

Comment: Уважаемый автор вопроса, а Вы не могли бы добавить формулровку задачи, котрую решает код? Так было бы проще...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не оперировать большими числами, можно привести основания обоих чисел к одной разрядности. А дальше сравнивать показатели степени и сами числа.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    x1,p1 = input().split()
    x2,p2 = input().split()
    n1,n2 = len(x1), len(x2)
    x1,x2 = int(x1), int(x2)
    p1,p2 = int(p1), int(p2)

    if n1 < n2:
        d = n2 - n1
        p1 -= d
        x1 *= 10**d
    elif n1 > n2:
        d = n1 - n2
        p2 -= d
        x2 *= 10**d
        
    if   p1 < p2: print("<")
    elif p1 > p2: print(">")
    elif x1 < x2: print("<")
    elif x1 > x2: print(">")
    else:         print("=")
```

---

А в вашем коде просто надо избавиться от лишних преобразований (число-строка-число). И уж тем более не вычислять каждый раз числа в каждом if.

```
import sys
t = int(sys.stdin.readline())
for i in range(t):
    x1, p1 = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    x2, p2 = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    v1 = x1 * 10**p1
    v2 = x2 * 10**p2
    if   v1 > v2: print('>')
    elif v1 < v2: print('<')
    else:         print('=')
```

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение чисел не далеко ушло от сравнения строк. Начнём с простого: чем длиннее число тем оно больше.

Если два числа одинаковой длины, то их можно сравнивать посимвольно начиная со старших разрядов. Первый отличающийся разряд определяет какое число больше, какое меньше. Это описание полностью совпадает с способом, которым упорядочиваются строки (не числа).

Последняя идея: если у двух чисел длинные нулевые хвосты, нет смысла их сравнивать. Достаточно сравнить ненулевые старшие разряды.

В программе только две операции с исходными значениями как с числами. Всё остальное - строковые операции. В комментариях примеры значений.

```
n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    s1, p1 = input().split()
    p1 = int(p1)                            # '1999', 100

    s2, p2 = input().split()
    p2 = int(p2)                            # '2', 103

    len1 = len(s1) + p1                     # 104 = len('1999') + 100
    len2 = len(s2) + p2                     # 104 = len('2') + 103

    if len1 < len2:                         # 104 < 104
        print('<')
    elif len1 > len2:                       # 104 > 104
        print('>')
    else:                                   # 104 == 104
        max_len = max(len(s1), len(s2))     # 4 = max(len('1999'), len('2'))
        s1 = s1.ljust(max_len, '0')         # '1999' -> '1999'
        s2 = s2.ljust(max_len, '0')         # '2'    -> '2000'
        assert len(s1) == len(s2)           # 4 == 4

        if s1 < s2:                         # '1999' < '2000'
            print('<')
        elif s1 > s2:                       # '1999' > '2000'
            print('>')
        else:                               # '1999' == '2000'
            print('=')
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока на ум пришло это.
Но есть две ситуации, вроде этих:

```
2 1
19 0

100 1
10 2
```

которые пока не понимаю как обработать без "тупого" преобразования в число.

---

Код:

```
import sys
t = int(sys.stdin.readline())
for i in range(t):
    x1, p1 = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    x2, p2 = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    if x1 < x2:
        if p1 <= p2:
            print('<')
        elif p1 > p2:
            print('idk') # <--
    elif x1 == x2:
        if p1 < p2:
            print('<')
        elif p1 == p2:
            print('=')
        elif p1 > p2:
            print('>')
    elif x1 > x2:
        if p1 < p2:
            print('idk') # <--
        elif p1 >= p2:
            print('>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще таким путем пойти (по сути это решение "в лоб"):

```
# для наглядности ввод заменил на input()
d = lambda n1,n2: {n1 < n2: '<', n1 > n2: '>'}
f = lambda x,y: int(x)*10**int(y)
for i in range(int(input())):
    print(d(f(*input().split()), f(*input().split())).get(True, '='))
```